# How to return the corresponding implementation on a jndi search?

Tags: java, jndi, java-ee-6

I have base class called `TransportObject`, which has `Ship` and `Plane` as subclasses. They all have a `Transponder` installed.

All of them can send GPS signals, receive signal or send/receive radio signals with their `Transponder`. However, the Transponder needs to do that in a different manner (different logic/code). `Transponder` is a `@Local` interface. There is a semi-abstract Implementation of the `Transponder`, which implements methods that are common to all implementations of the `Transponder`: the `TransponderAbstract`.

I thought about separate the logic of the different TransportObject's in sub classes of the `TransponderAbstract`. e.g. `ShipTransponder`, `PlaneTransponder` and implement the method sendSignal, listenToSignal, sendRadio, listenToRadio, etc.

my question: In a (Weblogic) Java EE environment, how can I inject or lookup the correct implementation of the `Transponder` in the `Ship` or `Plane` class?

e.g.

```
// from the Ship class
Object transponderImpl = ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/myApp/Transponder");
transponderImpl.sendSignal("13.54;46.34");
```

How does JNDI know that I like to operate with

```
ShipTransponder
```

?

Is my question clear? thanks for any recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the return value of `lookup()` to the correct type.  The object already has a type, but the compiler does not know what it will be at runtime.

```
Transponder transponderImpl = (Transponder)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/myApp/Transponder");
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But how would JNDI know that it must deliver an instance of the ShipTransponder?

Comment: Somewhere some component must have registered an object on that name.  The JNDI mechanism will return whichever object was registered.  What do you get now from this code:  `Object o = ctx.lookup(...); System.out.println( o.getClass() );`